# Why My project Run goodly But dont shown in emolator?

Tags: linux, android-emulator, launching

I am a new linux user and when I installed eclipse and sdk for android in linux.I get below error
when I start emolator and wait for 15 minute. I ran my project.my project run very good and below message is shown.

```
[2013-05-30 09:53:13 - RamzNegar] Android Launch!
[2013-05-30 09:53:13 - RamzNegar] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-30 09:53:13 - RamzNegar] Performing com.elmos.ramznegar.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-05-30 09:53:13 - RamzNegar] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-05-30 09:53:22 - RamzNegar] Uploading RamzNegar.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-05-30 09:53:23 - RamzNegar] Installing RamzNegar.apk...
[2013-05-30 09:53:39 - RamzNegar] Success!
[2013-05-30 09:53:39 - RamzNegar] Starting activity com.elmos.ramznegar.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
```

but i cannot show anything in emolator
I see below image
if answer is ~my emolator not run yet~;why my emolator dont run
how i can solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first time that you run emulator it will run very slow
and when you run your app ,eclipse didnot get you error
I think this is a bug for google
I hope that speed of emulator will be improve